# IP address recording for online voting

Tags: ip, voting-system

I'm about to start running an online vote (I'm just running the site, not doing any coding), and as part of the process of voting, the voter would need to click a confirmation email to register the vote.

The IP addresses are recorded to stop multiple accounts from voting, but my question is what IP will be recorded, the IP from the computer that placed the vote, or the IP from the computer that confirmed the vote?  (If they were done on different computers of course)

Comment: It depends how the system was written.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both.  Record one at vote placement, and another at vote confirmation.

BTW, if you use e-mail account, and suppose that one person = one e-mail, you don't need IP address.